# admissible tuples vs. prime tuples

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Let $\rho^\ast(x)$ denote the maximal length of an admissible sequence in $[1,x]$, i.e. of a sequence which does not cover all the residue classes modulo any $n\geq 2$. Hensley and Richards (1974) showed that $\rho^\ast(x)>\pi(x)$ for $x=20000$, hence under the prime tuples conjecture we also have $\pi(x+y)>\pi(x)+\pi(y)$ for the same $x$ and some $y$.

Clark and Jarvis (2001) found that already $x=4916$ satisfies $\rho^\ast(x)>\pi(x)$. Are their any smaller values of $x$ available, has anyone worked on this question since? Clark and Jarvis (2001) also showed that $\rho^\ast(x)\leq \pi(x)$ for $2\leq x\leq 1426$.

**Added.** As Wojowu remarked, $x=3159$ is also known to satisfy $\rho^\ast(x)>\pi(x)$.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture) tells us that $3159$ works.

Comment: @Wojowu: Thank you! This Wikipedia entry is a good reference.

Comment: [This page](http://www.opertech.com/primes/k-tuples.html) seems to analyze things in great detail. In particular, it tells us that the smallest such $x$ satisfies $2529<x\leq 3159$. Last update was in 2009 though, so progress might've been made.

Comment: @Wojowu: Thank you again. I recommend that you write up your comments as a response. (I will wait a few days and then accept the best response up to that point.)